# AWS RDS: not accessible from my local athough security group has inbound permission on my ip or All

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

I can able to access RDS after doing public accessible YES.

But not able to access it when public accessible NO.

I have the below set up

I used same SG and subnets of my rds.

The SG has
[image]

also in VPC NACL has below inbounds

[image]

Note:

**Here in answers some of the guy giving link where I understand theoretically.
can you tell me the exact solution of how to access RDS from my local machine using ec2 or any way**

Comment: Can you post screenshots of 2 sets of configuration: 1 with public accessible (that you are able to access your RDS), the other one without accessible (only your IP that you are not able to access your RDS)? Each set comprises of Security group Inbound & Outbound rule, NACL Inbound and Outbound rule!

Comment: Are you trying to access Amazon RDS from your own computer on the Internet? If so, you must set `Publicly Accessible = Yes` otherwise the DNS name will not resolve publicly.

Comment: Why do you want to set `Publicly Accessible = No`?

Comment: For not access it outiside the vpc. So I am able to access it now by creating a new ec2 instance and set its SG to mysql/aurora with tcp 3306 and also in the rds SG inbound rule gave the SG of the ec2 instead my local ip...now access without public accessible...Please let me know

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to enable Public accessibility if you want to be able to connect to your RDS instance from outside of your VPC. Enabling public accessibility provides a DNS address which is publicly resolvable. Please refer to [Working with a DB Instance in a VPC - Amazon Relational Database Service](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/USER_VPC.WorkingWithRDSInstanceinaVPC.html) for further details.

You do not need this to be turned ON if you are only going to connect from within your VPC. Refer 
to [Scenarios for Accessing a DB Instance in a VPC - Amazon Relational Database Service](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/USER_VPC.Scenarios.html#USER_VPC.Scenario1) for further details.

Comment: Can I able to access RDS using ec2 of using same vpc ??

Comment: I understand this theoretical knowledge Can you tell me what should I do to access it ?  should I create ec2 with same vpc and access it ??